# Visual Studio 2015 update 2 - Git is showing me in changes all the bin\debug and obj\debug folder/files , why would it be ignoring the gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, gitignore

I had created a new project on a computer with **vs 2015 update 2**,  I **commit** and **sync** to visual studio **TFS** free online repository.   Then I had pulled down a clone onto another computer, and after a few days of creating new files etc... I did a rebuild, builds fine, then I go to **Team Explorer** --> **Changes**

I'm seeing in Changes, that there are 138 ... of which  .txt, .dll , .cache, .pdb etc..
  Of course I "could" simply not "stage" those , but why would visual studio 2015 (upate 2) even be showing me these files.  ( I recall other projects with git / visual studio in which it simply does not show

```
 bin\Debug

 obj\Debug
```

What happened?  Why is it doing/showing this?

(gitignore issue?)

Comment: Well, actually it does not even look to have a .gitignore file at all!  :/   I suppose I have to add that...  I don't understand why Visual Studio / visualstudio.com   simply would not have that somehow by default

Comment: Even adding in .gitignore with the proper visual studio type of generic template does not even remove very many files,  instead of 138 files, I have 126 files ,  all those  dlls etc...   ughh

Comment: Someone would vote to close ?  Hmm,  that is interesting considering that visual studio / c# users are an extremely dominant crowd on stackoverflow.com and git with visual studio is being slowing introduced to thousands of Microsoft shops on a regular exponential basis,  so voting to close has zero merit.  This is a problem many will see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are going to have to hammer on it from the command line.

I have not gotten results with the simple delete of  .git\ `ms-persist.xml` 
That file gets re-created..

1. zip of your project to be sure to not lose any of your files / work on your remote ...

2.

```
cmd>

git status   ( i would do this frequently for peace of mind

Keep your 1 or more .gitignore file in the project folder(s)


git commit -m "all your files"   (save your code)

git rm -r --cached .     (remove any changed files from index (stage) 

git add .   ( add all files  which will remove .dll etc..

git commit -m "now your gitignore will work..."
```

Comment: Ok,  I see what that did,  thank you ,  I seen several articles with some overlapping information,  but some of the advise seems really bad....   thx again